# git log --remotes --decorate shows a deleted branch?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm using `git log --oneline --remotes --decorate` (didn't think `--oneline` was relevant so it's not in the title) and I get this log (names and messages changed).

```
$ git log --oneline --remotes --decorate
0efdd55 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge pull request #1 in FOO/bar-service from develop to master
cec3034 (origin/develop, develop) Merge pull request #2 in FOO/bar-service from refactor-top-level-components to develop
a847a00 (origin/refactor-top-level-components, refactor-top-level-components) Remove an unnecessary file to fix compilation
029e107 (origin/feature/refactor-top-level-components) Add .gitignore, remove editor specific files and compiled output
72dffaf Initial bar service Commit
```

I accidentally made the `feature/refactor-top-level-components` branch through BitBucket after I made `refactor-top-level-components` locally. I pushed `refactor-top-level-components` and deleted `feature/refactor-top-level-components` through stash. Why does it still show in the logs? Is it not actually deleted or is there some log flag I'm using wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try doing `git fetch origin --prune` to get rid of removed remotes